# Does a PageDown plugin exist for Jeditable?

Tags: plugins, markdown, jeditable, pagedown

I am using the jQuery [inline editing plugin Jeditable](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/jeditable). Thankfully, [Jeditable provides a plugin capability](http://www.appelsiini.net/2007/8/custom-input-types) for extending the out of the box inline editing it provides.

I am hoping to not reinvent the wheel-- as such does a [PageDown](http://code.google.com/p/pagedown/) plugin already exist for Jeditable? If one does my Google-fu is not turning up any results.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I never found a ready to go Jeditable PageDown plugin so I wrote my own. The below example is too specific to be used without modification, but should provide a decent enough outline for anyone endeavoring to accomplish a similar task.

Code to add a "markdown" input type to Jeditable:

```
var converter = Markdown.getSanitizingConverter();

$.editable.addInputType('markdown', {
    element: function(settings, original) {
        var editorId = original.id.substring(original.id.lastIndexOf("-"));
        var input = $('<textarea />');
        input.attr('id', 'wmd-input' + editorId);

        var panel = $('<div class="wmd-panel" />');
        panel.append('<div id="wmd-button-bar' + editorId + '" />');
        panel.append(input);
        panel.append('<div id="wmd-preview' + editorId + '" />');

        $(this).append(panel);
        return (input);
    },
    plugin: function(settings, original) {
        var editorId = original.id.substring(original.id.lastIndexOf("-"));
        var editor = new Markdown.Editor(converter, editorId);
        editor.run();
    }
});
```

The above code goes through a bunch of gyrations concerning the elements id, because in my case I can have several editors on a single page. See the [PageDown documentation](http://code.google.com/p/pagedown/wiki/PageDown) about Markdown.Editor for more details.

Once I've added the "markdown" input type to Jeditable it's just a matter of utilizing it with this code:

```
$('.editable-element-area').editable('http://jsfiddle.net/echo/jsonp/', {
    onblur: 'submit',
    type: 'markdown',
    indicator: 'Saving...',
    loadurl: 'http://jsfiddle.net/echo/jsonp/', // retrieve existing markdown
    callback: function(value, settings) {
        $(this).html(converter.makeHtml(value)); // render updated markdown
    }
});​
```

I want my users to see the markdown as HTML when they aren't editing it so I have to make use of the callback and loadurl [Jeditable parameters](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/jeditable). The load url retrieves the text to edit in markdown format, while the callback converts the new text back to html.

Comment: would it at all be possible for you to create a fiddle, faddle or something to demonstrate this?